# Looking for a HP fanfiction- severitus?

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

I'm looking for a Harry Potter fanfiction — I don't think it was a completed work or maybe was just a one shot. I only recall reading one chapter. In the story there's a scene with Harry, Dumbledore and Snape in Dumbledore's office. Harry is upset because Snape is to become guardian/ caretaker for him — either to pose as his father or due to some recent discovery of their relationship. It ends with Albus siding with Snape, and saying "Listen to your father, Harry".

Other details include a parental spell used for toddlers/small children and their magical outbursts? Due to a lack of safe calming potions for that age group.

I really thought it was posted on ffn, but multiple searches through there and ao3 have come up empty. Thanks for taking the time to read this!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?

Comment: Within the last year- year and a half.

Comment: For reference, [Severitus](https://fanlore.org/wiki/Severitus_(trope)) is a sub-genre of HP fanfics where Snape is Harry's father.